# Quadratic Differential Equation and Stability of Roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In a very simple setup where we have the following expression:

$\frac{d B(t)}{d t} = a B(t)^2 + b B(t) + c$

evaluating the stability points is easy. I can evaluate the system where the derivative equals 0 and and solve the quadratic equation using the quadratic formula.

How should I go about evaluating the stability of the roots (one or two) i.e. which root is stable and which one is unstable? Assuming of course that at least 1 root exists.

Is there a simple trick to evaluate this?

Comment: Break it into a two dimensional system and do the usual Jacobian.

Comment: @TinPhan what do you mean by break it down into a two dimensional system?

Comment: I apologize, I misread the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Suppose you have two real roots, say $x_1<x_2$ when you solve the equation. Now assume $a>0$. Then, you can easily see that $f(x)$ is positive when $x<x_1$ and $x>x_2$ (meaning your function B(t) is increasing), but negative when $x_1<x<x_2$ (meaning B(t) is decreasing.) Therefore, solutions converge to $x_1$, but diverge from $x_2$. So $x_1$ is stable while $x_2$ is unstable.

You can do the same analysis when $a<0$.

Comment: Great. That makes perfect sense. Is it then in general always true that larger root will be unstable if a>0? Does this also mean that if we have single root it will be stable from left but unstable from right (is there a more formal way of saying this?)?

Comment: yes. take a look at this link. What you are doing is classifying the equilibrium points an autonomous ODE and it can be done by visualizing the phase line diagram, which is what I roughly described above. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)